# Python code to generate True and False in a column

Tags: python, boolean-operations

I have assigned a task to create a column saying "Pass" with boolean values - "true/false" but with a certain condition that the column should have 80% True values and 20% False.

I tried creating the column Pass with random True/False values but was unable to get how to generate 8/10 true and remaining False.

My code is below:

```
Pass=[] 
i=1 
while i<5:
    choices=random.choice([True,False])
    Pass.append(choices)
    i+=1
```

Please help me with suggestions or a block of code for reference. Thanks

Comment: `random.choice([True] * 8 + [False] * 2)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `random.choices` and provide weights:

```
import random
# For a single Element
random.choices([True, False], weights=[8, 2])[0]
```

`random.choices` can return multiple samples, so it gives you a one-element list. If if you already know how many values you need (number of rows), you can also tell `choices` how many it should generate:

```
# For multiple Elements
random.choices([True, False], weights=[8, 2], k=20)
# [False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices), you can save a little work by supplying cumulated weights instead of weights:

```
random.choices([True, False], cum_weights=[8, 10], k=20)
```

---

tl;dr:

```
Pass = random.choices([True, False], weights=[8, 2], k=4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the probablity with [`random.choice()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with the `p`-parameter.

```
import numpy as np

print(np.random.choice([True,False],size=5,p=[0.8,0.2]))
```

**Output:**

```
[False  True False  True  True]
```